# JSOUP parsing XYZ.tor2web.org

Tags: java, jsoup, tor

Here is a program which downloads google.com and parses it.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.com").timeout(3000000).userAgent("Mozilla").get();  
        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
        for(Element l: links){
            String link = l.attr("abs:href");
            System.out.println(link);
        }
```

This works all dandy and prints out the links. But, if I change the parsed URL to this:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://idnxcnkne4qt76tg.tor2web.org").timeout(3000000).userAgent("Mozilla").get();
```

Then it outputs this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:425)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:446)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:410)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:164)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:153)
at quiz.MultipleChoice.main(MultipleChoice.java:10)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
... 17 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
... 23 more
```

Help please?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you use *HTTP* while *HTTP****S*** is required, or: You use a plain connection while an encrypted is expected.

If you browse to `http://idnxcnkne4qt76tg.tor2web.org`, you'll get redirected to `https://idnxcnkne4qt76tg.tor2web.org/`

Use the second URL (with the `https://`) and test again.